# Unable to drop index on a db2 table

Tags: db2

I have a table MAIN_SCHEMA.TEST in which I created a Index on a column CHECK_ID.
CHECK_ID is also a FOREIGN_KEY constraint in TEST table.

This table contains only 50 records.

By Mistake the index got created in Default schema DEFAULT_SCHEMA.CHECK_ID_IDX.

CREATE INDEX DEFAULT_SCHEMA.CHECK_ID_IDX(CHECK_ID ASC);

So I am trying to drop this index but the drop query gets stuck for long time.

DROP INDEX DEFAULT_SCHEMA.CHECK_ID_IDX.

there are no locks on this table when I checked.

Comment: The reason the `drop index` gets "stuck for a long time" is locks. You just have not found the locks, probably because you did'nt look correctly.  Configure your database with a short LOCKTIMEOUT setting (example 30 seconds) as per documentation. Then any query that waits for a longer time will fail with a specific sqlcode and reason-code (for example -911 reason code 68).  For a trivial 50 row table, you can also just create a new table and copy the rows over from the old table.  This is just simple admin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping and recreating the index with the right schema, could you just try to [RENAME](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020196.html) the index? It requires the existing **SCHEMA.NAME** pair together with the new as input. It will not move any data, but just update the metadata.

Comment: Actually, I want to alter the schema change the ordering of the columns defined in the index